# Coding using for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a neater way writing the for loop without using the `range(len(menu))`?

```
menu = ["msg", "contacts", "games", "settings", "media", "web"]

for option in range(len(menu)):
    print(menu[option])
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
This is contained in any tutorial on lists.

Comment: Do you mind accepting my answer? It really helps me out and will make it easier for others to find.

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
menu = ["msg", "contacts", "games", "settings", "media", "web"]

for option in menu:
    print(option)
```

Comment: Seems obvious now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Python `for` loops work like `foreach` loops in other languages. So you can iterate over the list directly.

```
for x in menu:
    print(x)
```